# is it possible to pre-compiling library JavaScript to pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, compiler-construction

I use JQuery to code in JavaScript. It's easy, less coding, more readable. 
When we compare JQuery to pure JavaScript, the JQuery is around 80% slower than pure JS.

So, JQuery (or other JS library) is a very good thing for the developer but at the end become a bad thing for the user : slower to load, slower to run.

JavaScript is running on the client side.

So, in my opinion, if I want to code easily with a frameworks it's my business.

It the developer's problem and the client don't have to see the difference.

I am wondering if is possible to code in JQuery, and compile it (locally) on a pure JavaScript.

I mean something like lesscss.

---

### DOM access with Jquery

this JQuery code is faster to write but is 80% slower than pure JS : [performance report](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-native-js-test)

for example, the JQuery code :

```
   $('#mydiv').css('backgroundColor', 'red');
   $('#mydiv').hide();
   $('#mydiv').html('hello');

   $('#content .col').each(function () {
       $(this).html('ok')
   });
```

would be compiled to pure JS :

```
 document.getElementById('mydiv').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
 document.getElementById('mydiv').style.display = 'none';
 document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = 'hello';

 var query = document.querySelectorAll('#content .col');
 for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
      query[i].innerHTML = 'ok';
 }
```

---

### prototype.js class declaration

this prototype.js déclaration is faster to write but is 98% slower than pure JS : [performance report](http://jsperf.com/jquery-class-create-vs-pure-js-function/3)

for example the prototype.js code :

```
var Animal = Class.create({
  initialize: function(name, sound) {
    this.name  = name;
    this.sound = sound;
  },

  speak: function() {
    alert(this.name + " says: " + this.sound + "!");
  }
});
var cat = new Animal('Kitty', 'Meow');
cat.speak();
```

would be compiled to pure JS :

```
function Animal(name, sound) {
  this.name = name;
  this.sound = sound;
}

Animal.prototype.speak = function() {
  result = (this.name + " says: " + this.sound + "!");
}

var cat = new Animal('Kitty', 'Meow');
cat.speak();
```

---

At the end, the question is about to have good tools to code quickly without impact on the user.

Comment: Do you have any real speed concerns on a real project with a jQuery based ria or is this only benchmark porn?

Comment: *"is it possible to pre-compiling Jquery to native JavaScript ?"* jQuery is not a language, it's a library of functions written in JavaScript. You may mean "native DOM" or "native browser."

Comment: The short answer is No

Comment: Are you using a common public CDN, like google, for the jquery script src URL?

Comment: Of course it is possible. You could build/use some JavaScript interpreter that resolves jQuery calls until you only have native instructions.

Comment: For a start, you should learn to write better code. `$('#mydiv').css('backgroundColor', 'red').hide().html('hello'); $('#content .col').html('ok')` is faster as well.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, but it's just for the example.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I mean works with the JQuery library just for the development coding and have a pure JavaScript code for running

Comment: @DirkLachowski I have to make a very efficient Javascript code. I want to use a library like JQuery to ease coding but it's look like a bit slower.

Comment: @Paul No, I use a local script, but the problem is from the coding

Comment: _"I want to use a library like JQuery to ease coding but it's look like a bit slower"_. Maybe it's a problem with your jQuery-fu. Any chance you could show us that way to slow code so we could suggest some improvements?

Comment: @DirkLachowski I don't have a significative example for now. I have created jQuery code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9NpSa/1/). This script finds all input and textarea in the form and add validation. It's a convenient script to create a contact form easily. So, for the developer (me) it's good but for the user it's not. In spite of the contact form will not change the script will check it in every single computer. 
My question is about the same problem. I figure out they are two different part, dev part and user part, however in Javascript both are mixed.

Comment: `is it possible to pre-compiling Jquery to native JavaScript?` No! it already is native javascript. You can optimize it here and there, but ultimately it won't really improve in performance until you just remove jquery completely.

Comment: Now im puzzled. I've looked at your fiddle but can't find any problems with the execution speed. Maybe i'm getting you totally wrong. What do you mean by _the script will check it in every single computer_? Why could this be a problem? The script runs on the local user's browser - this will scale linear. Could you elaborate on this point?

Comment: @DirkLachowski I mean, the script will parse the DOM of every client page to check how many form they are. But the HTML page is static and give the same number of form every time, in every computer. It's not really efficient at the end. My question is very theoretical, because my goal is to find the best way to develop JavaScript with the best user performance. At this time, if I improve my development rapidity, I regress the script performance.

Comment: Hm, sounds to me like _premature optimization_. You should give this a try: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/80084

Comment: @DirkLachowski yes, maybe it's a "_premature optimization really the root of all evil_" but for example the prototype class creation is 98% slower than pure JS. However, it's faster to declare a class with prototype in spite of pure JS ...

Comment: why I got -1 on my question ???

Answer (score 1):

I've not had any personal experience with this, but Google Closure Compiler might be your best bet.

https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/?csw=1

"It parses your JavaScript, analyzes it, removes dead code and rewrites and minimizes what's left."

This should make your code more efficient, although I'm not sure how effective it would be at specifically optimizing jQuery. It is unlikely you'll actually get fully "native" JavaScript.

Comment: @DirkLachowski In no way? OP is essentially asking for a way to inline and unroll and optimize the jQuery library code. This points to a program that might have the best shot at doing so.

Comment: @delnan Nope, OP is asking for an (automatic)  way to replace jQuery functions by native DOM manipulation. I can't see how the closure compiler should do that in a browser independent way.

Comment: @DirkLachowski At the end of the day jQuery calls those native DOM functions, it's just hidden beyond several layers of function calls and data structures. And browser feature testing, yes, but that's a minor point and the equivalent hand written native-DOM-manipulating code would have to do that too. Eliminating those is the holy grail of compiler optimization. I actually doubt the Closure compiler will actually succeed at it, but it's not completely off.

Comment: @delnan I agree (btw. this woodworking vs. meat pie comparison was really funny, sad you removed it). But i think you got my point - in the OPs problem the closure compiler will not help (well, maybe on IE6 or some hardware from the dark ages but that's another story).

Comment: @Lacius in my mind, Google closure compiler is more like a minifier than compiler. It's minify the code but don't really improve the internal performance.

Comment: @Intuitisoft: It's not directly related to your question, but you're mistaken about the Closure compiler. It does a lot more than minifying, even in simple mode. For instance, it can inline functions to avoid the over head of function calls. (Now, the overhead of function calls in JS is already *really really small*, but the point is that's much more a compiler than minifier thing to do.)